# Default rout every time redirect to one page

Tags: reactjs

I have routes in my application.

```js
<Router>
  <Switch>
     <Redirect exact from="/" to="/login" />
       <Route  path={'/login'} component={Login}/>
       <Route  path={'/'} component={A}/>
       <Route  path={'/b'} component={B}/>
       <Route path="*" component={NOT}/>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Every time when i access the application i am redirected to `/login`, but the issue appears when i want to access another page, because i also will be redirected on login page. Why this happens? And how to avoid this? How to be able to accesss every route, but in the same time the default route to be `/login`?

Comment: I couldn't able to understand the exact issue you are facing @AskMen. The above code for path '/' will always be redirected to login component and not to component A.

Comment: @Sachidhanandhan, the issue is next: every time when i access the application i am redirected to `/login` what is ok, but if i want to change the url, by writing in the browser, for example `/b`, i also will be redirected on login. Why?

Comment: if thats the case, you can move the <Redirect exact from="/" to="/login" /> before  <Route path="*" component={NOT}/>. This way you can access the login, A and B component via route.

Answer (score 0):

`Switch` renders the route that matches the location.

In your case, When you enter '/b' in the browser, it matches the location `<Route path={'/'} component={A}/>` but not `<Route  path={'/b'} component={B}/>`. So the component A will be rendered.

Check the code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/a-simple-react-router-v4tutorial-uxbm8?file=/components/Main.js)